# How to run a .NET launcher on Chrome without NPAPI

Tags: .net, google-chrome, npapi

I am not too knowledgeable regarding .NET; however I am very much aware of the NPAPI plugin deprecation occurring with Chrome.

There is a service that my company's support site uses that utilizes a .NET launcher to initialize a remote desktop connection. What I do not quite understand is if it is possible to utilize such a launcher on Chrome without the use of NPAPI.

Anybody care to enlighten me?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/ppapi/

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of PPAPI, asm.js, NaCL as alternatives; does this mean the only way to run .NET without NPAPI is to use these alternatives? There aren't HTML5 methods? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole point of HTML5 is to be completely standalone; to replace external technologies like Flash or .Net.

Comment: I completely understand that. I am basically going back with and forth with Oracle on this as they had sold us this service and they are not giving me a straight answer as to whether this service will work on Chrome after September 15th. I cannot think of any circumstances where a .NET launcher could run without NPAPI unless they were using PPAPI or some other plugin. Thanks for your input, hope this comment clarifies where I am coming from.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single solution that will work on all browsers; however, NPAPI still works on most and on Chrome you can use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

PPAPI is frequently quoted as being a solution by people not fully familiar with it; unfortunately you can only use PPAPI within NaCL or if you are specifically whitelisted by the browser team or with command-line arguments, and NaCL can't be used to launch an external process. The only solution on Chrome that I'm aware of to do what you want is [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

FireBreath2 (currently in the refactor branch of the github repo) has support for doing things like this via native messaging as well as NPAPI or ActiveX, but it does not have any support for .NET. It's also in alpha stage, in use in production but not well documented.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. In short, is there a pure HTML5  approach to work with a .NET launcher? I am basically going back and forth with Oracle as they are providing this service and they are not giving me a clear indication of whether or not this service will still work on Chrome after it deprecates NPAPI. I doubt that they are going to do a PPAPI or Native Messaging approach as [they are pretty much saying don't use Chrome if you need Java or any NPAPI functionality...](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)

Comment: No, there is no pure HTML5 approach that will allow you to talk to anything outside of the browser; that would be directly contrary to the design goals of HTML5.